# Membership price set order is wrong

Tags: civicontribute, price-sets

I'm having an issue all of a sudden with the ordering of Membership price sets on contribution pages. They are being displayed in an odd sequence that is confusing. It was never like this in the past and seemed fine before today. Additionally, making deliberate changes to the ordering has no effect on the output.

I've cleared caches with no discernable effect. I have disabled the new searchkit based admin and search interfaces with no change. I attach screenshots of the profile editor and the output.

CiviCRM 5.68.0 on WordPress 6.4.2

[image: screenshot of profile editor]

[image: screenshot of output showing incorrect field ordering]

UPDATE: I have tried many things including recreating the price sets in the correct order so I don't have to re-shuffle after the fact. That seemed to work for a time, but now the new versions are having the same problem.

Further, I have attempted to recreate the problem over at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org as [@petednz - fuzion](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/96/petednz-fuzion) suggested. The problem does not occur there.

This same site had a [relationship cache issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46082/relationships-no-longer-working-as-expected-data-corruption) and I wonder if there are other caches that are screwed up and what I might do to reset them?

Comment: Looks like a bug

Comment: What is the Civi version?

Comment: CiviCRM 5.68.0 on WordPress 6.4.2

Comment: Have you replicated on one of the Master sites?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I have not. Remind me where they are again? I just had a look at civicrm.org and couldn't see any clear links. The demo sites that I saw don't seem to be the latest version.

Comment: I just go to https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in CiviCRM 5.69+: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28842